# LinEst function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to teach myself some basic VBA in Excel 2010 and I've come across a problem I can't google myself out of. The objective is to create a button which when pressed, automatically does linest for me and writes the values into an array. So far, this is my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim linest As Variant
    Dim linestArray(4,1) as Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j as Integer

    linest = Application.LinEst(Range("U49:U51"), Range("T49:T51"), True, True)

    For i = 0 To 4
       linestArray(i,0) = accessing values of linest variable fyrst column
       Cells(68 + i, 21) = linestArray(i,0)
    Next

    For j = 0 To 4
       linestArray(j,1) = accessing values of linest variable second column
       Cells(68 + j, 22) = linestArray(j,0)
    Next

End Sub
```

How do I access the values of variable linest so I can store them to an array and print them? Thank you.

**EDIT: I figured it out. Variable linest is already an array! I feel pretty dumb. Sorry, this can be ignored.**

New code:

```
    Dim linestArray As Variant
    linestArray = Application.LinEst(Range("U49:U51"), Range("T49:T51"), True, True)
    For i = 0 To 4
        For j = 0 To 1
            Cells(68 + i, 21 + j) = linestArray(i + 1, j + 1)
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Don't feel dumb. Everyone has had moments like these, just most of the time they aren't posted publicly for all too see (or they were deleted!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of any such formula is a Variant array. So you've got that part right.

For a general approach to these `Application.` (use `WorksheetFunction.` instead, it's much faster) type functions is...

1. Type the function in Excel (as an array formula, `Ctrl-Shift-Return`, if need be)
2. The output is an N x M matrix of some sort (N =1 , M =1) for most cases
3. When you do `Var = Application.Linest(xyx)`, the answer gets stored in `Var`
4. Get the size of the `Var` using `Ubound(Var, 1)`, `Ubound(Var, 2)` to get number of rows and columns (note that these are base 0 type arrays)
5. Usually, the size will be `one x one`. In that case, your variable is stored in `Var(0,0)` i.e. a zero base multidimensional variant array, the top left element.

Hope this helps.